# onTouchListener one ImageView needs to be clicked twice to work, another only once

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    RelativeLayout rl;
    int i, j = 0;
    final int imageArray[] = { R.drawable.w1, R.drawable.w2, R.drawable.w3 };
    int image;
    final int imageCount = 3;

    ImageView back, save, next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        final int imageArray[] = { R.drawable.w1, R.drawable.w2, R.drawable.w3 };
        image = imageArray[0];

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlBackground);

        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
        save = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
        next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bNext);

        back.setOnTouchListener(this);
        save.setOnTouchListener(this);
        next.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bBack:
            if (j == 0) {
                j = imageCount;
            }
            image = imageArray[j - 1];
            rl.setBackgroundResource(image);
            j = j - 1;
            break;
        case R.id.bSave:
            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = 2;
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image,
                    opts);
            // savePicture(bm, "image_name.jpg");
            SaveImage savefile = new SaveImage();
            savefile.SaveImagee(this, bm);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Image saved on your gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.bNext:
            if (j != imageCount) {
                rl.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[j]);
                image = imageArray[j];
                j = j + 1;
            } else {
                j = 0;
                rl.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[j]);
                image = imageArray[j];
                j = j + 1;
            }
            break;

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The Problem: If I click on save button it works on the first click. If I click next button, I need to click it twice to trigger the function, but after that, if I continue to click next button, it works with one click. But when I switch to button back, it needs to be clicked two times and then only one time and if I switch back to button next, the same happens - two times, one time..
I guess it has something to do with focus.

If I change my `ImageView` to `ImageButton`, it triggers the function twice, If I add an if statemt`(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)` then again I have to click the button two times.. I want the button to work with one click all the time. I don't understand why this is happening, because save button works with one click all the time..

**EDIT:** If I change

```
image = imageArray[j];
```

to

```
image = imageArray[2];
```

then the button works at first with one click, still, I can't get it.

Comment: Why aren't you using an onclicklistener?

Comment: "If I change my ImageView to ImageButton, it triggers the function twice," is this true if you change to `onClick()` instead of `onTouch()`?

Comment: Your bNext's else block always results in `j` equaling `1`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I've been messing with my code, so it probably isn't right now. but that's not the point. please help me with my double click problems not anything else. Everything else works fine. 

@FD_ I used onClick before and it had the same result. had to click two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I set ImageCount = 3, but in arrays it start counting from 0, I programmed that value at the start of this app and I tought it can't be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You should really use an OnClickListener,

but maybe it is because you aren't telling the system you have handled the touch event. Try returning true when you deal with the touch event and false otherwise. For example:

```
 switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bBack:
        if (j == 0) {
            j = imageCount;
        }
        image = imageArray[j - 1];
        rl.setBackgroundResource(image);
        j = j - 1;
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
```

Comment: I used OnClickListener before, but I was told to use onTouch to solve my problem, now I am told to use onClick, the problem still is the same. And your answer doesn't solve my problem, the same still happens.